# Converting Map<String,String> to Map<String,Object>

Tags: java, string, optimization, dictionary, hashmap

I have Two Maps

```
Map<String, String> filterMap 
Map<String, Object> filterMapObj
```

What I need is I would like to convert that `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, Object>`.
Here I am using the code

```
        if (filterMap != null) {
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : filterMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String value = entry.getValue();
                Object objectVal = (Object)value;
                filterMapObj.put(key, objectVal);
            }
        }
```

It works fine, Is there any other ways by which I can do this without iterating through all the entries in the Map.

Comment: Why not use the putAll api method, in case you want to keep both the references.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Instead of writing your own loop that calls `put`, you can `putAll`, which does the same thing:

```
filterMapObj.putAll(filterMap);
```

(See [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29).)

And as Asanka Siriwardena points out in his/her answer, if your plan is to populate `filterMapObj` immediately after creating it, then you can use the constructor that does that automatically:

```
filterMapObj = new HashMap<>(filterMap);
```

But to be clear, the above are more-or-less equivalent to iterating over the map's elements: it will make your code cleaner, but if your reason for not wanting to iterate over the elements is actually a performance concern (e.g., if your map is enormous), then it's not likely to help you. Another possibility is to write:

```
filterMapObj = Collections.<String, Object>unmodifiableMap(filterMap);
```

which creates an unmodifiable "view" of `filterMap`. That's more restrictive, of course, in that it won't let you modify `filterMapObj` and `filterMap` independently. (`filterMapObj` can't be modified, and any modifications to `filterMap` will affect `filterMapObj` as well.)

Comment: @PrasadKharkar: I wouldn't say that my solution is better than yours, just that they serve different purposes. (And yours hints that the OP may have an XY problem.) Nothing wrong with having both. :-)

Comment: Hi @ruakh, why do we have to return an unmodifiableMap for the casting to work ? Can't java assert that a collection of String, String for instance can be returned as a collection of String, Object ?

Comment: @Antonin: For a "cast" from `Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, Object>` to be safe, *something* needs to make sure that the `put` method never adds inappropriate mappings to the original map (keeping in mind that the original map is very likely to be an instance of something like `HashMap` that doesn't do runtime type-checking). `unmodifiableMap` is not the only way to accomplish that, but it's among the simplest (and, I daresay, usually the most appropriate).

Comment: @asanka's answer is straightforward: 
`Map<String, Object> filterMapObj = new HashMap<>(filterMap);`

Comment: @Philippe: Good point. I'll add something about that.

Comment: With static import and the deduction of generic types using `Collections` just looks like: `final Map<String, Object> filterMapObj = unmodifiableMap(filterMap);`; which is short, clear and, as my understanding, no performance penalty. I think that's the best approach

Answer (score 12):

You can simply write

```
Map<String, Object> filterMapObj = new HashMap<>(filterMap);
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest answer. I would vote for it being "most correct."

Comment: This was the one that worked for me, and solved the problem in just one line of code.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the wildcard operator for this. 
Define `filterMapObj` as `Map<String, ? extends Object> filterMapObj` and you can directly assign the `filterMap` to it. You can learn about [generics wildcard operator](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/28/generics-the-wildcard-operator/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use putAll method to solve the problem.The Object is the father class of all objects,so you can use putAll without convert.