# MulitvaluedMap<String, String> to MultivaluedMap<String, Object>

Tags: java, hashmap, type-conversion, multivalue

I have a `MultivaluedMap<String, String> strMap` which i want to convert to `MultivaluedMap<String, Object> objMap`.

I tried exploring a few routes in the post below but none of them seem to work.

[Converting Map<String,String> to Map<String,Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21037263/converting-mapstring-string-to-mapstring-object)

Comment: What do you mean with "seem to work"? Haven't you tested them? Why not?

Comment: Could you add your code and the problem/error ?

Comment: Which `MultivaluedMap` are you asking about?

Comment: I think the under implementation of `MultivaluedMap` might like `<key, list<string>>`. If you convert it to `<key, list<object>>`, you must convert every value in list.

Comment: So you're referring to [`javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html), not some other implementation like e.g. [`org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiValuedMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html)?

Comment: Did you try `objMap = new MultivaluedHashMap<>(strMap)`?

Comment: @Andreas When OP uses the Apache Implementation, then that wouldn't be necessary. It also provides a `putAll()` implementation to perform the task like the linked answer explains. That is why I asked why OP didn't actually try it.

Comment: @Tom *"**When** OP uses the Apache Implementation"?* OP hasn't responded yet, but if you look at the two names I referenced, the Apache implementation actually has the wrong case for the `V` character in `Valued`, so it's most likely that OP uses the JAX-RS Implementation, not the Apache Implementation. --- Besides that, what do you mean by *"that wouldn't be necessary"*? Something would be necessary, and saying *"that wouldn't be necessary"* makes it sound like there's a *simpler* solution, but what is simpler than a lenient copy-constructor?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today, after a lot of searching, I came up with the following solutions:

```
public static MultivaluedMap<String, Object> asObjectHeaders(MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers) {
    if (headers == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> map = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() != null) {
                map.addAll(entry.getKey(), new LinkedList<Object>(entry.getValue()));
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

OR If you are using Guava, then you can use the following code:

```
public static MultivaluedMap<String, Object> asObjectHeaders(MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers) {
    if (headers == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return new AbstractMultivaluedMap<String, Object>(Maps.transformValues(headers, new Function<List<String>, List<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public @Nullable List<Object> apply(@Nullable List<String> strings) {
                if (strings != null) {
                    return new LinkedList<>(strings);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        })) {};
    }
}
```

OR If you are using jersey client glassfish, then you can use the following:

```
public static MultivaluedMap<String, Object> asObjectHeaders(MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers) {
    if (headers == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return new AbstractMultivaluedMap<String, Object>(Views.mapView(headers, LinkedList::new)) {};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same situation, Working solution-

```
MultiValuedMap<String, String> multivaluedMap = //store the value here 
Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = multivaluedMap.entries();

for(Map.Entry<String, String> ent : multivaluedMap.entries()){
    entityList.add(ent.getKey()+ " " + ent.getValue());
}
```